# exam questions on arrays and pointers and on insertion sorting

Tags: arrays, pointers, output

I'm doing some practice exams for my intro to C programming and I came across two questions for which I can't understand the output of the program.

Question 1:

What is the output of the following program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 8

void fun(int *x,int i) {
*x=*(x+i);
}
void main() {
int a[N]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},i;
fun(a,2);
for(i=0;i<N/2;i++)
printf("%d",a[i]);
printf("\n");
}
```

```
a) 1234    
b) 1313    
c) 2234    
d) 3232   
e) 3234 (right answer)
```

Question 2:

The following program attempts to sort an array in ascending order using insertion sort. It does not work as desired. What output does it produce?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void insertionSort(int a[], int n){
    int i, j, value;

for(i=0; i<n;i++) {
value = a[i];
j = i-1;

    while(j>=0 && a[j]>value) {
    a[j+1]=a[j];
    j--;
    }
a[i+1]=value;
}
}

int main() {
int i,a[]={2,7,6,3,1,9,5,4,8};
insertionSort(a, 9);

for(i=0; i<9; i++)
printf (" %d ",a[i]);
return 0;
}
```

```
a) 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1   
b) 2 2 7 7 7 7 7 9 9    
c) 2 2 7 7 1 9 9 4 8    
d) 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (right answer)    
e) 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: removed unnecessary information; fixed formatting

Answer (score 0):

In your first problem in the *fun* function you set a[0] to get the value of a[0+i] using pointers (with this command **x=*(x+i);* you specifically ask the head of the array to point at the address of the head plus 2 more wich is a[2]). This is why a[0] becomes a[2], so a[0]=3 and the rest of the array remains the same.

As for your next task, the problem is that in the insertionSort the value of a[1] in the first iteration will be replaced by *value*, so all the next while loops will be false and therefore only the command *a[i+1]=value;* will be executed and will set all element values to 2. If you remove this command you still won't get the sorting right because there's a problem in the while loop too. I will only post here an example of a right insertionSort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void insertionSort(int a[], int n){
    int i, j, value,t;

    for(i=0; i<n;i++) {
            value = a[i];
            j = i-1;

            while(j>=0 && a[j]>value) {
                        t=a[j+1];
                        a[j+1]=a[j];
                        a[j]=t;
                        j--;
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes a lot more sense now :)